Greek letters in labels with `gt`-tables for PDF documents
Is there a way of using Greek letters in column labels for tables produced with gt when the output is a PDF document?
Minimal example using Quarto to render:
---
format: pdf
---

```{r}
#| echo: false
gt::exibble |>
  gt::gt() |>
  gt::cols_label(
    "num" = "GREEK LETTER"
  )
```
  


@KJ: The issue is that the Latex code emitted from gt isn't allowing for e.g. Greek letters via math mode. I think it's an issue with the gt() function, so we might see a fix from the package author (relevant link: https://github.com/rstudio/gt/issues/1201)
